# Value of an html button is marked as undefined when trying to make changes to a sqlite database

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, sqlite

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Carrito</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

{% if 'user' in session %}
    <a href="/logout" class="button-54">Cerrar Sesión</a>
{% endif %}

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="button-54" class="dropbtn">Ver carrito</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Marca</th>
                <th>Referencia</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for cart_item, libro in cart_items %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ libro.marca }}</td>
                    <td>{{ libro.ref }}</td>
                    <td>{{ libro.price }} €</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div align="center" style="padding: 10px; width: fit-content; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; background-color: white;">
            <h2 style="padding: 5px; margin: 0;">Precio total: {{ total_price }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <h1 class="intro">scrapcatlog.com</h1>
</div>

<div class="buscador">
    <form method="post" action="/buscar" id="search-form">
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <input class="campo-busqueda" type="text" name="termino_busqueda" id="search-input" placeholder="Introduce un término de búsqueda">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" id="search-results">
    <tbody id="search-results-body">
        {% for row in data %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="titulo">Marca</h2>
                        <span class="datos">{{ row.marca }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="titulo">Referencia</h2>
                        <span class="datos">{{ row.ref }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="titulo">Precio</h2>
                        <span class="datos">{{ row.price }} €</span>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" action="/add_to_cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="libro_id" value="{{ row._rowid_ }}">
                        <button type="submit">Añadir al carrito</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="Imagen centrada" src="/static/images/{{ row.field7.lower() + '.png' }}" class="imagen-red" loading="lazy">
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-input');
    const searchResults = document.getElementById('search-results-body');

    searchInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
        const searchTerm = searchInput.value;
        fetch(`/buscar?termino_busqueda=${searchTerm}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => updateTable(data));
    });

    function updateTable(results) {
        // Actualizar dinámicamente la tabla con los resultados
        searchResults.innerHTML = '';
        results.forEach(row => {
            const newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            newRow.innerHTML = `
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="titulo">Marca</h2>
                        <span class="datos">${row.marca}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="titulo">Referencia</h2>
                        <span class="datos">${row.ref}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="titulo">Precio</h2>
                        <span class="datos">${row.price} €</span>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" action="/add_to_cart">
                        <input type="hidden" name="libro_id" value="${ row._rowid_ }">
                        <button type="submit">Añadir al carrito</button>
                    </form>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="Imagen centrada" src="/static/images/${row.field7.toLowerCase() + '.png'}" class="imagen-red" loading="lazy">
                </td>
            `;
            searchResults.appendChild(newRow);
        });
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've been working on a project similar to a catalog where I can add items to the cart. I've encountered an issue with dynamically generating a form in JavaScript.

In my HTML code, I have a table generated using Jinja2 template engine which displays items retrieved from a database. Each row contains a form with a hidden input field for `libro_id`.

Here's a simplified example of my HTML structure:

```
<form method="post" action="/add_to_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="libro_id" value="{{ row._rowid_ }}">
  <button type="submit">Añadir al carrito</button>
</form>
```

In my JavaScript function `updateTable`, I'm dynamically creating rows for the table based on the data retrieved from the server. However, when I try to assign a unique identifier `_rowid_` to each row, it works fine visually, but the `libro_id` value in the form is marked as undefined, preventing items from being added to the cart.

Here's the relevant part of my JavaScript code:

```
<form method="post" action="/add_to_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="libro_id" value="${row._rowid_}">
    <button type="submit">Añadir al carrito</button>
</form>
```

I've tried various approaches, including iterating through the `results` array using a `for` loop, but haven't been able to resolve this issue. Could someone please assist me in identifying what might be causing this problem and how to fix it? I'm using Flask with Python for server-side processing and SQLite for the database.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(row._rowid_);`, and what when you adapt your code to be like this: `row[_rowid_] = index; console.log(row);`? And why do you need it, anyway? You're only assigning it the value of `index`. What's preventing you from using `index` directly?

Comment: i get the error 10 undefined in both cases, it's like in the html i get the value that i need from the databese but when i try do get the value from the updated value from the search input, i cant find it

Comment: If you inspect the DOM element do you see the value?

Comment: If you look at the Network tab of your browser's DevTools when your request goes through, what do you see among the results you're getting back? Is the structure of those results something that you'd expect to get?

Comment: i tried that and i also tried to print it, in order to find out if there is  something inside it, but nothing...

Comment: OK, what do you get when you change this part: `.then(response => response.json())` to this `.then(response => console.log(response); response.json())`?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'undefined'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 164, in add_to_cart
    libro_id = int(request.form['libro_id'])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'undefined'